# How to get Spring to actually use configured LocalTime serializer?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm trying to get Spring (Spring Boot 2.2.4) to serialize `LocalTime` instances as `"hh:mm:ss"` instead of arrays `[h, m, s]`. So far, I've tried:

Setting `spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMP=false` in `application.properties`

Overriding the `ObjectMapper` config:

```kotlin
@Bean
@Primary // needed? Who knows
open fun mapper(): ObjectMapper {
  val mapper = ObjectMapper()
  val javaTimeModule = JavaTimeModule()
  // attempt 1
  javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalTime::class.java, myCustomSerializer)
  mapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule)
  // attempt 2
  mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
  return mapper
}
```

For attempt 1, I can see the module being registered, but if I override the `serialize` or `serializeWithType` methods, those are never called.
Attempt 2 simply has no effect.

How do I get Spring to actually call the custom ObjectMapper? Even a hint on what I could try to see why it's not being called could help.

Comment: What Web-framework do you use? Sprinb Web MVC or Flux?

Comment: Spring WebMVC (5.2.3, if it matters)

Comment: Removing your custom mapper and setting the `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false` should be all you need. Make sure you don't add an custom `ObjectMapper` as that will override the Spring Boot one and disable the use of `spring.jackson` properties. Can you show the code that is sending the response (the controller code and model).

Comment: @M.Deinum I've tried that option too. Just adding the property does nothing. For completeness' sake, when I do add a custom ObjectMapper bean and then inject an ObjectMapper in my endpoint (just to see if Spring uses it), it's a different ObjectMapper instance from what I created. So I'm pretty sure Spring is ignoring my custom ObjectMapper anyway. As for the configuration property, won't I need to install JavaTimeModule somehow?

Comment: No you don't as that is a well known module and automatically registered. So if you start messing around with your own defined ObjectMapper nothing of the `spring.jackson` properties apply. The same goes i fyou have your own `@EnableWebMvc` in your application. All of that disables Spring Boot autoconfiguration.

Comment: Well, there we go. I *do* have `@EnableWebMvc` in my app. And yes, disabling it makes the configuration work. Now, on to figuring out if my request interceptor will break when I disable WebMvc

Comment: @M.Deinum Since your suggestion answers the question, would you like to write up an answer? If you don't want to, I'll do it myself

Comment: The interceptor should still work if defined registered in a aclass implementing `WebMvcConfigurer` and in the `addInterceptor` method. This should still be picked up (assuming there is an `@Configuration` or `@Component` annotation on that class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining an `ObjectMapper` yourself or when adding `@EnableWebMvc` to your configuration this will stop Spring Boot from configuring its `ObjectMapper`. In turn it also renders the `spring.jackson` (and other `spring.mvc`, `spring.multipart`etc) properties useless as it is now assumed you manually configure things.

Basically you shouldn't have either of those and thus adding `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false` should all that needs to be done.

If that doesn't work, cheeck for `@EnableWebMvc` and/or a pre-configured `ObjectMapper`.